# How to improve performance on SQLite3 iPhone program

Tags: iphone, core-data, sqlite

I am (still) working on an iPhone program which uses SQLite3. I have managed to optimize the database writes as far as I can.

The problem I have now is that "END TRANSACTION" is killing me as it's taking very long. The journal file is usually about 50k which might be a problem, but I'd like to know your ideas.

I tried using "PRAGMA synchronous = 0", but that caused some data corruption. My latest attempt at optimizing is "PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE" but I do not know if that helps a lot.

Any suggestions at this stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the in memory journaling?

"PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY"

That was one of the most significant performance boosts for us.

If that is not quite fast enough yet, try the memsys5 stuff.
http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_memsys5

Comment: I've added that and seeing how it works. So far it has been very fast.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you add that, is it a one off or do you need to add it to each statement?